# ADLS - Accessing the ADLS from Databricks for SQL mode

Tags: databricks, aws-databricks

In Databricks , we are able to access the ADLS file based on the following authentication code in Python mode .But when I tried to Authenticate for SQL mode getting below error . Please help us to get information on how to declare authentication in sql.

Python :

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net","<access-key>")
df = spark.read.csv("abfss://<your-file-system-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>/<your-file-name>")
```

Sql:
reference:

error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you're using incorrect syntax. variables should be set with [`SET` keyword](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-conf-mgmt-set.html), like:

```sql
SET fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net = <access-key>;
```

after that you could run your query.